# Warning: error TS18002: The 'files' list in config file is empty

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, gruntjs

I'm using **TypeScript 2.1.5.0**. I've configured the `grunt-typescript-using-tsconfig` plugin as shown below but I get the error in the subject line when I execute the task.

The problem is the `tsconfig.json` property `"files":[]`. I didn't encounter this error when using `gulp-typescript`. Do you recommend that I configure something differently? Either my `gruntfile.js` for this plugin or `tsconfig.json`? Or can you recommend a different grunt plugin that will successfully hook into `tsconfig.json` and process the typescript task as expected?

```
typescriptUsingTsConfig: {
    basic: {
        options: {
            rootDir: "./tsScripts" 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or can you recommend a different grunt plugin that will successfully hook into tsconfig.json and process the typescript task as expected?

gulp typescript supports tsconfig : https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/#using-tsconfigjson

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(tsProject.src())
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `Gruntfile.js` configuration as shown in the following gist :

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        typescriptUsingTsConfig: {
            basic: {
                options: {
                    rootDir: './'
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-typescript-using-tsconfig');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'typescriptUsingTsConfig'
    ]);

};
```

***Note*** *the value for `rootDir` is set to `./` (i.e. The same folder as the `Gruntfile.js`).*

---

**tsconfig.json**

Then ensure you have your `tsconfig.json` configured to include a list of all `.ts` files to be compiled to `.js`. For example:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "files": [
    "./tsScripts/a.ts",
    "./tsScripts/b.ts",
    "./tsScripts/c.ts"
  ]
}
```

There are of course other compiler options you can set in [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

---

**Directory structure**

The configurations above assumes a directory structured as follows, however you can just adapt the code examples as required:

```
foo
├── Gruntfile.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsScripts
│   ├── a.ts
│   ├── b.ts
│   └── c.ts
└── node_modules
    └── ...
```

---

**Running grunt**

`cd` to the project folder, *(in these examples the one named `foo`)*, and run:

`$ grunt`

---

**Output**

Running grunt will create a folder named *dist* and output all `.js` files to it. For example:

```
foo
├── dist
│   ├── a.js
│   ├── b.js
│   └── c.js
└── ...
```

If you want the resultant `.js` files to be output to the same folder as the source `.ts` file, *(i.e. not to the 'dist' folder)*, just exclude the `"outDir": "./dist"` part from your `ts.config.json`.